# java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input behaving in a strange way

Tags: java

I am trying to take user input through scanner ,and submit this code on HackerRank and getting the above exception. I tried to run the same test cases on my machine and no Exception is caught there, code works fine.I am not that learned about streams in Java, help me find out error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution{
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException, Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = in.nextInt();
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (test < 1 || test > 10) {
            throw new Exception("Illegal test cases");
        }
        while (test-- > 0) {
            // System.out.println("Enter patient dna");
            String patient = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            // System.out.println("Enter virus dna");
            String virus = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            int l = virus.length();
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            if (patient.length() > 100000 || virus.length() > 100000) {
                throw new Exception("Input length out of bounds");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < patient.length() - virus.length() + 1; i++) {
                String sub = patient.substring(i, i + l);
                count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < sub.length(); j++) {

                    if (virus.charAt(j) != sub.charAt(j)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count == 0 || count == 1) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the entire error.

Comment: Why do you re-create scanner?

Comment: @BitNinja this error is found at line 15 that is ::
      String patient = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov because first scanner is taking integer input, if i dont recreate it , it runs unexpectedly on runtime while taking the inputs. I am also confused why it happens so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

After that use

```
while (in.hasNext())
{
    /// do the operation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NoSuchElementException will be throwed because the you are tring to read the data from the input (Scanner) where data is reached to the end.So you have to read the input( Scanner ) by checking hasNext() is true or false.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's correct. You should add some code showing what the solution looks like in their example.